# Matching Function Pointers in Clang-Query

Tags: c, function-pointers, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-static-analyzer, clang-query

What is the query to match a function pointer, e.g., in the following code:

```
int foo(struct A *a, int b)
{
    return a->x->y(b);
}
```

`y` is the function pointer to match.

Comment: Does it matter that your code is invalid?  You cannot return a value from a function declared to return `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, this is the answer for a call to a function pointer. The main difficulty was to detect the type of function pointers using the query. So I added the `ignoringParens(functionType())` traversal matcher to solve the problem. A simple usage of `functionType()` will not work.

```
match callExpr(hasDescendant(memberExpr(hasType(pointerType(pointee(ignoringParens(functionType()))))).bind("member")))
```